# Why can't I set screen brightness?

Tags: hp, brightness

I have an HP Pavilion g6 and can't adjust the brightness. I have specific buttons for this on my keyboard, but they are not working. Tried in System Settings too, but even if I change the brightness there nothing is happening. Tried through the terminal too but it did not work. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1809497), a user [solved his problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11095010&postcount=9) with [Kamal Mostafa's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-i915bri). But, this PPA is no longer supported and point out [another one](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight). Again, there is an explanation saying that Oneiric already includes this kernel. But, on some systems a boot parameter is still needed: `acpi_backlight=vendor`.

So, before you boot your system via Grub, just press "e" and put `acpi_backlight=vendor` at the end of kernel line. And start your system with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. If that works, edit your Grub file for permanent solution.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```